# Where does spark SWFLoader store the loaded file?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.6

I'm building two AIR apps - desktop and mobile.

When using the spark SWFLoader to load a **remote** SWF file, the desktop app seems to cache the file when loading for a second time (progress jumps to 100% instantaneously). In contrast, the mobile app will go through the same loading time even though the file has been loaded before.

So, my questions are:

1. Where is the loaded file being stored in the desktop app?
2. If there is caching, can we do the same for mobile app?

Comment: It is likely that caching in a mobile AIR app just doesn't happen b/c of the constrained environments of mobile devices. In web apps, Flash relies on the browser's cache... Thusly, there is no formal Flash API to manage such things.

Comment: Yes, I understand web app depends on browser's cache. But what about desktop app running on AIR? In the temp folder perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to set the sessionCachingEnabled attribute in your main application file to true. This is a neat feature that allows you to support (with no sweat) scenarios like this: the user navigates to the n screen of the application, he has some data on that screen and the application gets closed (maybe the user went to a new application or decided to close the app); when he opens the application again he will see the same screen as in the previous session.

```
       <s:MobileApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
         firstView="views.ASimpleMobileAppHome"
         sessionCachingEnabled="true"
          splashScreenImage="@Embed(source='loading.png')">
          ...
     </s:MobileApplication>
```